# Combine NextAuth Middle ware with a second middleware

Tags: typescript, next.js, middleware

I'm struggeling for weeks now and some how I'm totally lost.

Im trying to build a kind of a small monitor app with authentication.

I found out that you just can have one middleware file in next js in main folder.

This one I use for authentication

```
export  { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard/:path*", "/admin/:path*", "/users/:path*", "/main/:path*", "/editCv/:path*",  "/cv/:path*"] };
```

and this one I have build for a second function in middleware.

middleware2.ts

```
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname === '/') {
        console.log('TRACK!')
    }
}

export const matcher = {
    matcher: ['/'],
}
```

But my main goal is to combine them or make 2 seprate files and add up linking them in middleware.

if I combine them only the second one works but dropts the authication part. pleas help I'm trying to find a way myself but sadly still stuck.

I combined the files, I search on stackoverflow, reddit, asked ai but nothing so far I found out that you can just have one middleware.ts or middleware.js.

I got losted some how I need to have it combined.

below I have add some exapmles:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { default as NextAuthMiddleware } from "next-auth/middleware";

// Custom middleware function
export default async function AuthMiddleware(req: NextRequest): Promise<NextResponse> {
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname === '/') {
    console.log('TRACK!')
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}

// Configuration for custom middleware
export const AuthMiddlewareConfig = {
  matcher: ['/', "/dashboard/:path*", "/admin/:path*", "/users/:path*", "/main/:path*", "/editCv/:path*",  "/cv/:path*"] 
};

// Exporting NextAuth middleware and its configuration as AuthMiddleware
export { NextAuthMiddleware as AuthMiddleware, AuthMiddlewareConfig };
```

second try

```
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { default as nextAuthMiddleware, config as nextAuthConfig } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default async function combinedMiddleware(req: NextRequest) {
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname === '/') {
        console.log('TRACK!')
    }
    // Call next-auth middleware
    await nextAuthMiddleware(req);
}

export const matcher = {
    matcher: ['/'],
}

export const config = { 
    ...nextAuthConfig,
    matcher: [
        ...nextAuthConfig.matcher,
        "/dashboard/:path*",
        "/admin/:path*",
        "/users/:path*",
        "/main/:path*",
        "/editCv/:path*",
        "/cv/:path*"
    ]
};
```

second one

```
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";


export default async function name(req: NextRequest) {
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname === '/') {
        console.log('TRACK!')
    }
}

export const matcher = {
    matcher: ['/', "/dashboard/:path*", "/admin/:path*", "/users/:path*", "/main/:path*", "/editCv/:path*",  "/cv/:path*"],
}
```

a other try is to multi chain it but that keep up getting errors as well..

Comment: Can you show me how did you try to combine both?

Comment: Yes I wil added that, I did so many